# How can create tables and fields in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I tried create a table and its fileds via php/mysql

So, First I created a sql class:

```
<?php
class db{


    public $db;
    function __construct(){
        $this->db_connect('localhost','root','','dbmenu');
    }

    function db_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database){
        $this->db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

        if($this->db->connect_errno > 0){
            die('Unable to connect to database [' . $this->db->connect_error . ']');
        }
    }

    function setTables()
    {

        //for created Groups
        $_tableName="groups";
        $_fieldsName=array();
        $_fieldsName = array("id" =>"id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT",
                      "name"      =>"name varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL",
                      "parent"   =>"element varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL", 
                      "primary"   =>"PRIMARY KEY (`id`)");
        $this->createTable($_tableName,$_fieldsName);
    }

    function createTable($_tableName,$_fieldsName)
    {

    }
} ?>
```

can somebody guide me to write createTable($_tableName,$_fieldsName) function?

```
$db= new db;
$db=setTables();
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own ORM when there's many out there that already do all this and more?

Comment: Can u introduce a good one to me?

Comment: you've already got 90+% of the `create table` query string. The other 10% should be pretty easy to figure out.

Comment: Most [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) include one. For example, [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) has a [feature complete migration management system](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations). You should only write your own when the solutions out there are completely inadequate, and for simple things that should be extremely rare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your previous code, it will be something like

```
function createTable($_tableName,$_fieldsName)
{
    $this->db->query('CREATE TABLE '. $_tableName .
                     ' (' . join(',', $_fieldsName) .');');
}
```